# Probability of an event occurring at least once in the next 10 years if it occurred 116 times during the last 73 years?

Tags: probability

To be clear, this is the type of question I am trying to answer:

**An event occurred 116 times in the last 73 years. Based on *only* this information, what is the probability that it will occur at least once in the next 10 years? Or the next 20 years? Etc.**

For context, I’m trying to estimate the probability of a tornado occurring in a particular geographical area in a some arbitrary amount of years, based on the past 73 years of tornado records. I don’t care about being super technical here, I just want a rough probability without considering other factors.

Comment: Not really mathematics.  Maybe try stats.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

It is likely your dataset has information of the number of years with $0,1,2\ldots$ tornados.  That would be extremely useful.  It could be that every year has at least one tornado, in which case your probabilities are both $1$.  It could be that one year had all $116$ tornados and you could model it as $\frac 1{73}$ chance of many tornados in a given year.  In that case you have a pretty good chance of avoiding a tornado for $10$ years and not a bad one of avoiding one for $26$ years.

If you insist that there is no other data available, because there are more tornados than years, we would expect that most years have tornados.  Given that, the chance of a tornado in $10$ years is very high.  I would refuse to put a number on it because it would indicate more certainty than I think is reasonable.

All this depends on the last $73$ years being a reasonable model of what the probability is in the future.  As the climate seems to be changing, this may be a false assumption.  It may be better, it may be worse.